# Can rockets be deflected multiple times?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-pyro

Normally, without hesitation, as soon as a soldier launches a rocket my way, I (as a Pyro), (try to) deflect the rocket back at him.

As a Soldier, if ever there's a chance that one of my rockets will be deflected by a Pyro, I won't bother launching a rocket at him (I'll use the shotgun or rocket-launch his feet).

Now, today, I (as a Pyro) was up against a Soldier and a Pyro (the Pyro being in front). The Soldier launched a rocket at me, and, out of instinct, I didn't bother deflecting it, for fear of the Pyro in front of me deflecting it again. Is this a sensible thing to do? Could the Pyro have deflected my deflected rocket? Is there any limit to how many times a rocket can be deflected?

Long story short: Can rockets be deflected multiple times by Pyros? If so, then where does it end (could two Pyros keep deflecting the same rocket back and forth until one of them eventually runs out of ammo?)?

Comment: Deflecting uses ammo(gas), and I think that there was 200 gas and a deflect used 50 gasses. So, I guess if you had unlimited ammo, you'd have that chance but I believe that 200/50 = 4 times/per pyro (if haven't used any gasses yet) is the answer.

Comment: If this were possible we'd see 'Pyro-Pong' as a minigame :P

Comment: @ardaozkal Oh, yeah. I forgot about it using ammo! Apart from the ammo, could two Pyros keep deflecting the same rocket?

Comment: @alexqwx I believe that 'Pyro-Pong' would be possible if you had unlimited gasses. However, you can test it on a unlimited ammo server (a friend would help), I'd try it myself but its 1:30 am here and I don't want to make any sound.

Comment: @Robotnik I take it you've never heard of the Dodgeball game mode.

Comment: @Powerlord - Nope, I generally just play Capture Point or KOTH. Link YouTube vid?

Comment: @Robotnik http://youtu.be/1PW2MTcLimg  Note that in this game mode, rockets are homing.

Comment: WHO HASN'T HEARD OF DODGEBALL

Comment: @EpicGuy Me....

Comment: ardozkal: Airblasts for all flamethrower except the backburner cost 20 ammo!

Comment: I think the more important takeaway here is - you probably should've reflected that rocket.  Even if the Pyro COULD reflect it, you're counting on that Pyro having amazing reflexes, and assuming there's enough distance for him to reflect it back, there could be just enough distance for you to re-reflect it anyway, or just direct it away from that particular Pyro.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, a deflected projectile can be deflected again. With enough pyros or if the pyros are somehow getting more ammo, the same rocket can be deflected ad nauseum.

This video demonstrates a rocket being deflected this way:

Comment: Note that this video was edited. Check out [this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UvU8GQcaQz4&spfreload=10&channel=NISLT).

Comment: @EpicGuy Ooh, I like that one.

Comment: @Studoku Awesome! Thanks! Since deflected rockets mini-crit (+35% damage), does this damage accumulate every time the rocket is deflected, or does the damage remain at 35% of the damage of the original rocket?

Comment: @alexqwx It stays at +33%. Multiple mini-crit effects don't stack.